# running multiple celery worker from python script

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

i have a flask web application that needs to run 5 celery worker's which each one them needs to consume tasks from specific queue on redis.

is that possible to write a python script to do that? i have tried and  only could run one worker through python. also i am not sure if it is  a proper way to that.should i run celery workers as a daemon?

here is how i do that for one worker:

```
from myapp import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    argv = [
        'worker',
        '--loglevel=DEBUG',
    ]
    app.worker_main(argv)
```

i know this is possible to do with bash but i am more comfortable with python.

thank you.

Comment: do you really need to do this in a script? something like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) is generally a better way of running workers.